# openSUSE doesn't like the Internet -- can't connect with eth0

Tags: linux, networking, ethernet, opensuse

I just moved into a new apartment and the Internet guys came and set up the modem. I hooked a wireless router to the modem and all my Wi-Fi devices are working fine.

I plugged my computer into the router and the first thing I noticed was the LAN lights on my onboard LAN card were blinking orange (not heavily blinking, just a little). Usually it picks up the connection right away and I'm good to go. It doesn't.

I manually setting the IP for eth0 to an IP in the range of the ones my router was on (I changed it to 192.168.0.199).

I can login to the router and ping all devices on my network, but I can't grab the Internet. I tried connecting my laptop with an Ethernet wire just to see what would happen and it worked too.

My knowledge of networking is basic so any kind of help would be beneficial here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, suprisingly because I've never dealt with something like this before.

I googled the nameservers for my ISP and entered them in YaSt.
Voila! It's fixed.

Comment: What is YaSt and how do I add the nameserver there?